# Poor audio quality during RDP with thin client from Windows Multipoint Server 2012

Tags: remote-desktop, voip, audio, windows-multipoint-server

we have problems with **audio quality** from **Windows Multipoint Server 2012** during **RDP** sessions, we are using **Thin Clients** for the ***Remote Desktop*** the display is good but the **audio quality is bad**, there are background noises and the audio is broken during VOIP session on the Remote Desktop.

is there anyway to **fix or improve VOIP audio quality on multipoint** and also **get rid of the delay and background noise during the Remote Desktop sessions**?

Comment: From your other questions I strongly suspect you got ultra-cheap thin clients, that do not support RDP 7.1, and that is the source of your problem. What TCs are you using?

Comment: $60 thin clients from china. it supports RDP, the only problem is the audio because the latency is too high.

Comment: It supports **what version** of RDP?

Comment: sad to  say only 7.0

Answer (score 1):

You need third-party solution for sound redirection, like [Sound over RDP](http://www.sound-over-rdp.com/).